# Xcode C++ error: the code is the same but the output changes when I run it

Tags: c++, xcode

The code is to get the products of all other elements except itself without division.

It makes both prefix products and suffix products to get the result.

My output differs with the same code in Xcode.

When I run it, the last element is 0, 24, or some other big numbers even though they are from the same code.

I did not know why so I just tried changing random things.

I tried distance() instead of it-vec.begin().

I tried if in else.

I tried if else it==vec.end().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int>::iterator num;

vector<int> nums={1,2,3,4,5};

vector<int> prefix_products(nums.begin(),nums.end()); //  deducted

vector<int> suffix_products(nums.begin(),nums.end()); //  deducted


int main() {

    int j;// for printing


    //  prefix products
    for (num=prefix_products.begin(); num!=prefix_products.end(); ++num)
    {
        if (num==prefix_products.begin())
            *num=*num;
        else
            *num=*num * prefix_products[distance(prefix_products.begin(),num)-1];
    }


    //  vector (pp) printer
    for (j=0; j<prefix_products.size(); ++j)
    {
        std::cout<<prefix_products[j]<<" ";
    }


    cout<<endl;


    //  suffix product
    reverse(suffix_products.begin(),suffix_products.end());

    for (num=suffix_products.begin(); num!=suffix_products.end(); ++num )
    {
        if (num==suffix_products.begin())
        {
            *num=*num;
        }
        else
        {
            *num=*num * suffix_products[distance(suffix_products.begin(),num)-1];
        }
    }

    reverse(suffix_products.begin(),suffix_products.end());

    //  (sp) printer
    for (j=0; j<suffix_products.size(); ++j)
    {
        cout<<suffix_products[j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for (j=0; j<nums.size(); ++j)
    {
        cout<<nums[j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;


    //  result

    for (num=nums.begin(); num!=nums.end(); ++num)
    {
        if (num==nums.begin())
        {
            *num=suffix_products[distance(nums.begin(),num)+1];
        }
        else if (num!=nums.end())
        {
            *num=prefix_products[num - nums.begin()-1] * suffix_products[num - nums.begin()+1];
        }
        else
        {
           *num=prefix_products[distance(nums.begin(), nums.end()-2)];
        }
    };

    //  result printer
    for (j=0; j<nums.size(); ++j)
    {
        cout<<nums[j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0; };
```

expected:
120 60 40 30 24

actual_1:
120 60 40 30 24

actual_2:
120 60 40 30 0

actual_3:
120 60 40 30 -1182602672

actual_4:
120 60 40 30 786408 
.
.
.

Comment: Differences between different runs (with the same input) are almost a proof of Undefined Behaviour. You probably access vector out of bounds. Use a debugger, go through your code step by step to see what happens. Or change all `[]` to `.at()` method calls to get a nice exception on out-of-bound access.

Comment: Don't use iterators if you have to reverse-engineer the corresponding index afterwards anyway. Just write a plain `for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i)` loop.

Comment: not the problem but your loops can be nicer if instead of the `if-else` you let the loop start at `begin()+1` / end at `end()-1`. Also `*num = *num;` has zero effect

Comment: also `distance(nums.begin(), nums.end()-2)` is just `nums.size()-2`

Comment: I would suggest you to follow MaxLanghofs advice to use an index based loop when you need indexes. You probably have an out of bounds access that is easier to find when you dont mix iterators and indices

Comment: `*num=*num` does not initialize `*num`

Comment: Hello, Yksisarvinen. I tried it and I got an out put:  libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
(lldb)